# PHP username validation

Tags: php

I am working on writing a PHP login system. I have everything that I need working, but I would like to verify that a username entered during the registration only contains alphanumeric characters. So how could I take a variable, say $username, and ensure that it contained only alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/^\w{5,}$/', $username)) { // \w equals "[0-9A-Za-z_]"
    // valid username, alphanumeric & longer than or equals 5 chars
}
```

OR

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$/', $username)) { // for english chars + numbers only
    // valid username, alphanumeric & longer than or equals 5 chars
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the speedy answer! I have to wait 10minutes before it'll let me accept your answer, so I'll do it later.

Comment: `preg_match` is better suited here, also there is no need for character class.

Comment: The square brackets are redundant if you're only targeting one character or special character set (`\w`)

Comment: Also the definition of `\w` depends on the locale. If OP want to allow only English letters, it's safer to enumerate them.

Answer (score 8):

The Best way I recommend is this :-

```
$str = "";
function validate_username($str) 
{
    $allowed = array(".", "-", "_"); // you can add here more value, you want to allow.
    if(ctype_alnum(str_replace($allowed, '', $str ))) {
        return $str;
    } else {
        $str = "Invalid Username";
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about the length, you can use:

```
if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
   // Username is valid
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function filterName ($name, $filter = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]"){
    return preg_match("~" . $filter . "~iU", $name) ? false : true;
}

if ( !filterName ($name) ){
 print "Not a valid name";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late but I am using the following function to test usernames or other types of **alphanum-like strings**. It tests alphanum chars only by default but you can add more characters such as . (dot), - (dash) or _ (underscore) to the whitelist.

It will also prevent consecutive chars for the chars specified as `$more_chars`.

```php
function valid_alphanum_string($str, $more_chars = '') {
  # check type
  if (!is_string($str)) return false;

  # handle allowed chars
  if (mb_strlen($more_chars) > 0) {
    # don't allow ^, ] and \ in allowed chars
    $more_chars = str_replace(array('^', ']', '\\'), '', $more_chars);

    # escape dash
    $escaped_chars = strpos($more_chars, '-') !== false
      ? str_replace('-', '\-', $more_chars)
      : $more_chars;

    # allowed chars must be non-consecutive
    for ($i=0; $i < mb_strlen($more_chars); $i++) {
      $consecutive_test = preg_match('/[' . $more_chars[$i] . '][' . $escaped_chars . ']/', $str);
      if ($consecutive_test === 1) return false;
    }

    # allowed chars shouldn't be at the start and the end of the string
    if (strpos($more_chars, $str[0]) !== false) return false;
    if (strpos($more_chars, $str[mb_strlen($str) - 1])) return false;
  }
  else $escaped_chars = $more_chars;

  $result = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9' . $escaped_chars . ']{4,}$/', $str);

  return $result === 1 ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing the basic alpha-numeric username, You can check alphanumeric value with a predefined template like this:

```
preg_match([[:alnum:]],$username)&&!preg_match([[:space:]],$username)
```

The second part returns false if the string contains any spaces.